# Regular expression to match first and last character

Tags: javascript, regex, expression

I'm trying to use regex to check that the first and last characters in a string are alpha characters between a-z.

I know this matches the first character:

```
/^[a-z]/i
```

But how do I then check for the last character as well?

This:

```
/^[a-z][a-z]$/i
```

does not work. And I suspect there should be something in between the two clauses, but I don't know what!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The below regex will match the strings that start and end with an alpha character.

```
/^[a-z].*[a-z]$/igm
```

The `a` string also starts and ends with an alpha character, right? Then you have to use the below regex.

```
/^[a-z](.*[a-z])?$/igm
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dX3hD4)

**Explanation:**

```
^             #  Represents beginning of a line
[a-z]         #  Alphabetic character
.*            #  Any character 0 or more times
[a-z]         #  Alphabetic character
$             #  End of a line
i             #  Case-insensitive match
g             #  Global
m             #  Multiline
```

Comment: Lookahead is completely unnecessary here.

Comment: This is completely identical to the other answer.

Comment: he misses the `g` modifier.

Comment: Why do you need `g` modifier?

Comment: @M42 `g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)`

Comment: Sure, but it has nothing to do here because we match the whole string.

Comment: without g modifier, it fails to match the string in the second line.http://regex101.com/r/jO2pI2

Comment: Kudos to you for explaining that sh**! :)

Comment: @AvinashRaj, what should I do to make the first character== last character in your regex.

Answer (score 11):

You can do it as follows to check for the first and last characters and then anything in between:

```
/^[a-z].*[a-z]$/im
```

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/gH2yA2)

Comment: The flag `m` would help as well.

Comment: @hjpotter92, Thank you. I have included it in my answer

Comment: @sshashank124 `.*` would have done instead of `.*?`. Backtracking will be better because of anchor.

Comment: @Unihedron, Thank you. I have changed my answer. I guess I just feel safer with `.*?`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
/^.|.$/gim
```

it matches with first and last character

Answer (score 1):

```
 var str = "Regular";
//following code should return true as first and last characters are same
var re = /(^[a-zA-Z])(.*)\1$/gi;

console.log(re.test(str); //true

Match 1 : Regular
Group 1 : (^[a-zA-Z]) = R
Group 2 : (.*) = egula
\1$ : Match the same what is caught in group 1 at the end = r
```

Comment: That is not was asked.

Answer (score 0):

put characters in groups like ([group1])([group2])\1. The \1 says the last group matches group 1.

```
([a-z])([someRegex])\1
```