# How do I make a string invalid if it begins or ends with a dot?

Tags: php, regex

For example I want `.brewpixels`  and `brewpixels.` to echo

> your username is invalid

If the dot is anywhere between the first and last letter the script should echo

> your username is good

How do I change my regex to accomplish this?

```
$username = 'brew.pixels';

if(preg_match('/(^\d|[^\w])/', $username)){
    echo 'your username is invalid';
} else {
    echo 'your username is good';
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24340969/regular-expression-to-match-first-and-last-character

Comment: `(^(\.[\d\w])?|([\d\w]\.)?$)`

Answer (score 3):

The following will match strings that begin or end with a dot

(the trick is to escape the dot since it has special meaning in regex)

```
/^\.|\.$/
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/oA8uX8/1)

With additional conditions `only alpha num underscore and dot within the body`:

```
/^(\.[\w.]+|[\w.]+\.)$/
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/oA8uX8/2)

Simply to replace in your given code:

```
if(preg_match(regexToMatchBadWords, $username)){
    echo 'your username is invalid';
} else {
    echo 'your username is good';
}
```

---

Or, you can match directly the correct words by forcing the first & last chars to be alpha-num-underscore and the inner body to accept dots too:

```
/^(\w[\w.]+\w)$/
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/oA8uX8/3)

Which reverses the logic in your code:

```
if(preg_match(/^(\w[\w.]+\w)$/, $username)){
    echo 'your username is good';
} else {
    echo 'your username is invalid';
}
```

Comment: This works but I loose functionality. The regex I provided only allows alphanumeric characters and underscores. I want the final regex to do the same, and prevent dots at the beginning and end of a string.

Comment: @brewpixels You allow alphaNum chars + underscore + dots within the body right ?

Comment: yes that's right. But alphaNum chars and underscore can be outside of the body.

Comment: Try my last edit, if it doesnt work, i'll need examples to work on ! (be fast, i'll have to leave in 30min xD )

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are saying that you want it to have other regex info but you can do:

```
if (preg_match('/^\./', $username) || preg_match('/\.$/', $username) {
  echo 'invalid';
}
```

This will make .brew and brew. fail.

I forgot about the pipe character, see Enissays answer for the correct simpler way.