# javascript regex to check if first and last character are similar?

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there any simple way to check if first and last character of a string are the same or not, only with regex?

I know you can check with charAt

```
var firstChar = str.charAt(0);
var lastChar = str.charAt(length-1);
console.log(firstChar===lastChar):
```

I'm not asking for this : [Regular Expression to match first and last character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24340969/regular-expression-to-match-first-and-last-character)

Comment: Why do you want to use regular expressions for something that's so easily done without regex?

Comment: @DavidThomas , this is not the only rule that I'm checking , I'm checking lot's of others and I was wondering to see if I can do all of them in one regex.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use regex with [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and its [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) to assert both starting and ending characters are same by capturing the first caharacter. To test the regex match use [`RegExp#test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method.

```js
var regex = /^(.).*\1$/;

console.log(
  regex.test('abcdsa')
)
console.log(
  regex.test('abcdsaasaw')
)
```

[Regex explanation here :](https://regex101.com/r/MBDlnr/1)

1. `^` asserts position at start of the string
2. 1st Capturing Group `(.)`
3. `.*` matches any character (except newline) - between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
4. `\1` matches the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capturing group
5. `$` asserts position at the end of the string

---

The `.` doesn't include newline character, in order include newline update the regex.

```js
var regex = /^([\s\S])[\s\S]*\1$/;

console.log(
  regex.test(`abcd

sa`)
)
console.log(
  regex.test(`ab
c
dsaasaw`)
)
```

Refer : [How to use JavaScript regex over multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979884/how-to-use-javascript-regex-over-multiple-lines)

[Regex explanation here :](https://regex101.com/r/jQ7dHE/1)

1. `[.....]` - Match a single character present
2. `\s` - matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)
3. `\S` - matches any non-whitespace character (equal to `[^\r\n\t\f ]`)

finally `[\s\S]` is matches any character.

Comment: @Milad :  the test method check for pattern match

Comment: The pattern to match any character `[\s\S]` is equivalent to `[^]`.

Comment: @PranavCBalan , I know that dude , I meant which part is doing the magi c of checking the first and last char and why?

Comment: @Milad :  where `^` and `$` assert the start and end position(known as start and end anchors).... then the first char is captured using capturing group and check the last char as the same by back-reference (which is captured, `\1`)

Comment: This is not covering the case with one single character. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try it

```js
const rg = /^([\w\W]+)[\w\W]*\1$/;
console.log(
  rg.test(`abcda`)
)
console.log(
  rg.test(`aebcdae`)
)
console.log(
  rg.test(`aebcdac`)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    var rg = /^([a|b])([a|b]+)\1$|^[a|b]$/;

    console.log(rg.test('aabbaa'))

    console.log(rg.test('a'))

    console.log(rg.test('b'))

    console.log(rg.test('bab'))

    console.log(rg.test('baba'))
```

This will make sure that characters are none other than a and b which have the same start and end.

It will also match single characters because they too start and end with same character.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var re = /^([a-zA-Z]{1}).*\1$/; console.log(re.test('abcda'));

var re = /^([a-zA-Z]{2}).*\1$/; console.log(re.test('abcab'));
```

One can control the number of beginning and ending characters to match using:

> let re = /^([a-zA-Z]{1}).*\1$/; console.log(re.test('abcda'))

> let re = /^([a-zA-Z]{2}).*\1$/; console.log(re.test('abcab'))