# How do I restrict my last character using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regular expression :

```
new RegExp("[a-zA-Z]{1}[/]{1}" + userName + "[/]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$", "i")
```

This provides me much of my required results. However I am unable to check one condition:

I do not want my last character to be '-'. It could be present anywhere after second '/', just not the last character. More precisely last character should be anything `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` but not a hyphen '-'.

I checked out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24340969/regular-expression-to-match-first-and-last-character), but could not wrap my head around it. How is this done exactly.

Comment: This question is only related to JavaScript, I removed Perl tag.

Comment: However, that solution does not let you have 1 char in the last part of the string. It is just incorrect. `[^-]` is a character class that is a consuming pattern. Only a zero-width assertion solution is correct: based on anchors, word boundaries or lookarounds (lookahead/lookbehind).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Improving your regex `[/]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$`.

1. You don't need `[/]{1}`, you can simply use `/` *(except in a literal regex object that is delimited by slashes, in this case you need to escape it `\/`)*
2. `-` within character class should be places either at beginning or at end to avoid matching ASCII ranges. You used `[a-zA-Z0-9-_]`. Instead you could just use `[\w-]`. `\w` is shorthand for character class `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

> It could be present anywhere after second '/', just not the last character.

Just make the last character `non-hyphen` using `[^-]` at end.

**Regex:**

`new RegExp("[a-zA-Z]/" + userName + "/[\w-]+[^-]$", "i")`

**OR**

`new RegExp("[a-zA-Z]/" + userName + "/[\w-]+\w$", "i")` if the last character is strictly within the `\w` character class.

**[Regex101 Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/NqyM4z/2/)**

**[Regex101 Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/NqyM4z/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

In your particular case, you may add a word boundary before `$` since all other chars you match are word chars:

```
new RegExp("[a-zA-Z]/" + userName + "/[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+\\b$", "i")
                                                    ^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fUBMSW/1)

Else, use a negative lookahead, which is a more universal solution that will work regardless of what chars you match here:

```
new RegExp("[a-zA-Z]/" + userName + "/(?!.*-$)[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$", "i")
                                      ^^^^^^^^
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qur18u/1).

Some notes:

- `/` needs no escaping when you use it inside a constructor notation
- `{1}` is always redundant as each atom is matched once by default
- `\\b` needs double escaping because a word boundary is a combination of a literal `\` and the letter `b`, and if you use `"\b"`, it will match a backspace char
- **NOTE**: if `userName` contains special regex chars, you'd better consider [**escaping the variable contents**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) to be parsed as literal chars.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
new RegExp("[a-zA-Z]{1}[/]{1}" + userName + "[/]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]$", "i")
```

Answer (score 0):

in case last character should not match `-`, the last `-` has to be removed from last character set :

```
new RegExp("[a-zA-Z]{1}[/]{1}" + userName + "[/]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$", "i")
```

to be changed to

```
new RegExp("[a-zA-Z]{1}[/]{1}" + userName + "[/]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]$", "i")
```

also `{1}` are useless because it's implicit

```
new RegExp("[a-zA-Z][/]" + userName + "[/][a-zA-Z0-9-_]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]$", "i")
```

Answer (score 0):

Or simply

```
new RegExp("^[a-z]/" + userName + "/[\w-]*\w$", "i")
```

I.e. your  character class `[a-zA-Z0-9-_]` is the same as shorthand class `\w` - *word character*, plus hyphen - `[\w-]`. And ending the match with `\w` will do what you want - not allowing a hyphen at the end.

In the first regex `A-Z` is unnecessary because the whole thing is case insensitive thanks to the `"i"` flag.