# Match the same start and end character of a string with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I'm trying to match the start and end character of a string to be the same vowel. My regex is working in most scenarios, but failing in others:

```
var re = /([aeiou]).*\1/;
re.test(str);
```

Sample input:

- `abcde`, output - false (Valid)
- `abcda`, output - true (Valid)
- `aabcdaa`, output - true (Valid)
- `aeqwae`, output - true (Not valid)
- `ouqweru`, output - true (Not valid)

Comment: In what scenarios is it failing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular Expression to match first and last character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24340969/regular-expression-to-match-first-and-last-character)

Comment: What does \1 mean?

Comment: \1 matches the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capturing group

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You need to add anchors to your string.

When you have, for example:

```
aeqwae
```

You say the output is true, but it's not valid because `a` is not the same as `e`. Well, regex simply matches the previous character (before `e`), which is `a`. Thus, the match is valid. So, you get this:

```
[aeqwa]e
```

The string enclosed in the brackets is the actual match and why it returns `true`.

If you change your regex to this:

```
/^([aeiou]).*\1$/
```

By adding `^`, you tell it that the start of the match *must* be the start of the string and by adding `$` you tell it that the end of the match *must* be the end of the string. This way, if there's a match, the whole string must be matched, meaning that `aeqwae` will no longer get matched.

A great tool for testing regex is [Regex101](https://regex101.com/). Give it a try!

**Note:** Depending on your input, you might need to set the global (g) or multi-line (m) flag. The global flag prevents regex from returning after the first match. The multi-line flag makes `^` and `$` match the start and end of the **line** (not the string). I used both of them when testing with your input.

Comment: The only thing missing from the above answer for me, was, how do you then re-use the value matched at the start for the end? ... what is the \1 for?

Comment: "Capturing group. (regex) Parentheses group the regex between them. They capture the text matched by the regex inside them into a numbered group that can be reused with a numbered backreference." So I guess I just answered my own question. Thank you for the awesomely cool answer. Now, onward and forwards to understand (g) (m) et. al.

Comment: To understand what **\1** actually does, you might want to see this : https://javascript.info/regexp-backreferences#backreference-by-number-n

Comment: You might have to add another \ to escape, to avoid a potential "Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode" error.

Answer (score 6):

Just a different version of @Hristiyan Dodov answer that I have written for fun.

```js
regex = /^(a|e|i|o|u).*\1$/

const strings = ['abcde', 'abcda', 'aabcdaa', 'aeqwae', 'ouqweru']

strings.forEach((e)=>{
  const result = regex.test(e)
  console.log(e, result)
})
```

Answer (score 6):

Correct answer is already mentioned above, just for some more clarification:

```
regEx= /^([a,e,i,o,u])(.*)\1$/
```

Here, `\1` is the backreference to match the same text again, you can reuse the same backreference more than once. Most regex flavors support up to 99 capturing groups and double-digit backreferences. So \99 is a valid backreference if your regex has 99 capturing groups.[visit_for_detail](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
/^([aeiou])[a-z]\1$/
```

just a bit of improvement, to catch alphabet letters.

Comment: You regex expression `[a-z]` must match and only match once alphabet letters, for example, "aa" and "axxa" will not matched. But you give a good advise, I use `/^([aeiou])[a-z]*\1$/` to instead.

Comment: To catch only one you can add `{1}` like so /^([aeiou]{1})[a-z]+\1$/